# LINQ to SQL - Self Join Child to Parent (Same Table)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

For some reason I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to do this.

I have a table of message posts. (It is part of a very large existing legacy system, and I can't change the way the tables are defined.) There is only 1 table of posts. It is a two-level hierarchy. Each post is either a "parent" or a "child". Children are posts replying to parents. (There are no other levels.)

So for example, very simply there might a Posts table that looks like this:

```
ID,ParentID,Content,UserID
===========================
1,0,"Hello",3
2,1,"Reply to Hello",7
3,1,"Another Reply to Hello",4
4,0,"New Post",2
...etc...
```

So imagine that a very simple Posts table is defined like this:

```
INT ID [identity value for the post],
INT ParentID [0 == no parent, otherwise the value is the parent identity value]
TEXT Content [just imagine it is text]
INT UserID [the author of the post]
```

Here's the problem. I would like to find all replies made to a particular User.

So, for example, if I wanted to find all replies made to UserID #3 above, I should come up with this:

```
ID,ParentID,Content,UserID
===========================
2,1,"Reply to Hello",7
3,1,"Another Reply to Hello",4
```

That's because UserID #3 posted post ID #1, and those two were replies.

It is simple to find all parent posts by UserID #3. I would just do this:

```
var posts = (from db.Posts
  where p.UserID == 3
  && p.ParentID == 0 // this is a parent
  select p).ToList();
```

Likewise, to find all child (reply) posts not made by UserID #3, I would just do this:

```
var posts = (from db.Posts
  where p.UserID != 3
  && p.ParentID != 0 // this is a child
  select p).ToList();
```

But how do I find all replies made ONLY to UserID #3???

Imagine the Posts table has 1,000,000 rows from the last 10 years, and there may only be 3 rows that are replies, so I can't exactly just brute all of it into some List and then sort through. I need to do 1 LINQ to SQL query that only returns the needed 3 rows.

If I could do this, it would work:

```
int userId = 3;
var posts = (from p in db.Posts
  where p.UserID != 3
  && p.ParentID != 0 // this is a child
  && DID_USER_CREATE_POST(userId,p.ID) // can't do this -- since this imaginary C# function won't work here
  select p).ToList();
```

I think I need to do some sort of self-join (???), since the parent and child are in the same table, to come up with those 3 needed rows.. but I have yet to figure out how to do this with the existing table structure.

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this using LINQ to SQL. I'm using C# and the code will be in an ASP.NET MVC controller (that emits RSS).

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have proper Foreign Key setup, the LINQ should see the reference, so your query would be something like this.

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts
  where p.Parent != null //Looking for children only
  && p.Parent.UserId == 3 //UserId of the parent post
```

The reference object might be called differently. If you don't see any of this kind of object, you can achieve the same thing by join as well.

```
from post in db.Posts
join parent in db.Posts on post.ParentId equals parent.ID
where parent.UserId == 3
select post
```

I omitted the other simpler `where` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this against a data structure like you have, but it may get you there:

```
var id = 3;
var query =
from p in db.Posts
join r in db.Posts on p.ID equals r.ParentId
where p.UserId == id && p.ParentId == 0
select new { Post = p, Reply = r};
```