# Recursive linq results returning duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

This question builds off of one I asked last week: [Recursive linq to get infinite children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337202/recursive-linq-to-get-infinite-children).  The answer given in that post produced what I needed; a distinct list of Locations and their children based on a parent.  We needed to use our own model for Locations, so we created one, and since then, I've been getting duplicate results.  Our model is very basic:

```
class LocationModel
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public int ParentLocationID { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set;}
}
```

If you compare it to the entity created by EF, I just cut out all the fields we don't need/use (see link above).  So I modified my linq statements to use this new model instead:

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

public IEnumerable<LocationModel> GetAllChildLocations(int parentId)
{
    var locations = (from l in db.Locations
                        where l.ParentLocationID == parentId ||
                        l.LocationID == parentId
                        select new LocationModel()
                        {
                            LocationID = l.LocationID,
                            ParentLocationID = l.ParentLocationID,
                            LocationName = l.LocationName
                        }).ToList();

    var children = locations.AsEnumerable()
                            .Union(db.Locations.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(x => x.ParentLocationID == parentId)
                            .SelectMany(y => GetAllChildLocations(y.LocationID)))
                            .ToList();
    return children.OrderBy(l => l.LocationName);
}
```

When I run it, either in Visual Studio or in LinqPad, I now get duplicates.  Here's the original code that does **not** produce duplicates:

```
public IEnumerable<Location> GetAllChildLocations(int parentId)
{
    var locations = (from l in db.Locations
                        where l.ParentLocationID == parentId ||
                        l.LocationID == parentId
                        select l).ToList();

    var child = locations.AsEnumerable()
                        .Union(db.Locations.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.ParentLocationID == parentId)
                        .SelectMany(y => GetAllChildLocations(y.LocationID)))
                        .ToList();
    return child;
}
```

Why is it producing duplicates when I use my own model vs. the generated one from EF?  Does it have to do with the auto-generating fields that the EF model has and mine doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it producing duplicates when I use my own model vs. the generated one from EF?

Because you are using `Enumerable.Union` method which by default uses *reference* equality. EF `DbContext` change tracker keeps internally (tracks) the already loaded *entity* object instances with the same PK (even if you retrieve them via separate database queries), hence the reference equality works. Which cannot be said for the `new LocationModel` instances created by the query `select` operators.

One way to resolve it is to implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in your `LocationModel` class. But in general I don't like the implementation of the recursive children retrieval and the usage of `Union` - there must be a better way, but this is outside the scope of this question (but for the linked).

The root of the evil for me is the following condition

```
where l.ParentLocationID == parentId || l.LocationID == parentId
```

which selects both the item and its children, leading to duplicates in the result set, which then are supposed to be eliminated by the `Union` method. The good implementation will not generate duplicates at all.